# Defining mapDispatchAsProps as simple actionCreators object does not pass props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Reading the [redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), specifically on `react-redux`, there is a less verbose way of binding action creators to the dispatch function, using a simple object of actionCreators, passing it as the **2nd** argument of redux's `connect`.

However, if I just pass in this object OR manually bind the action creators, `this.props` is empty (except for count). I don't get my `increment`, `decrement`, `reset` or `dispatch` in props. Manually calling dispatch in the arrow functions make the functions appear in props.

```
export const increment = () => ({ type: "INCREMENT" });

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  increment
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  // WORKS: ******************** (manually calling action creator and dispatching new action)
  dispatch => ({
     increment: () => dispatch(increment())
  })
  // DOES NOT WORK: ************ (passing as simple 'actionCreators' object)
  // mapDispatchToProps,
  // DOES NOT WORK EITHER: ***** (manually binding action creators to dispatch)
  // dispatch => bindActionCreators(mapDispatchToProps, dispatch)
)(Counter);
```

I have simplified the code in above, but the code sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-water-w0430?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: My guess is because you have an unnecessary circular dependency. Move your store to its own file, then import that file in your components (including in the bootstrapping of the app).

Comment: Wow! I just refactored my actions into an actions.js out of index.js, and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: I currently don't use my store directly outside of index.js, but I guess you mean to take refactor store and the reducer into a separate file. Index.js would only have the render/ return method?

Comment: Yes, try to split your code in files that are focused on one thing. If it looks like it's doing too much, split further, make new directories, in which you can create new index files, export what you want, etc. You should (almost) never need circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Emile Bergeron for the comment.

**I had a circular dependency.** My `index.js` was importing the component from `Counter.js`. The component in `Counter.js` was importing action creators from `index.js`. As soon as I refactored the actions out into a separate file, it worked.